# Lateral aliasing in databases

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, teradata

Is Redshift the only database that supports a lateral alias? https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/amazon-redshift-announces-support-for-lateral-column-alias-reference/. For example, this allows for something like:

```
SELECT 
    ... AS something
    something * 2
FROM
    tbl
```

I believe teradata (or maybe one of the other DWs) support it but I can't find a reference.

Comment: Teradata supports it for decades. Of course, this breaks the rules of Standard SQL, but it's nice to have. Something similar can be achieved by the Outer/Cross Apply syntax in some other databases.

Comment: @dnoeth can you link to the part of the docs where Teradata has that?\

Comment: @dnoeth can you link to the Teradata docs for this?

Comment: Not easy to find :-)  https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Fundamentals/June-2022/Basic-SQL-Syntax/Referencing-Object-Names-in-a-Request/Using-a-Column-Alias

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
select 1 col1, col1*2 col2;
```

Comment: what database is this? And could you please send me a link to the place in the Teradata docs where this feature is mentioned??